# Python Nested functions within a class that update the class instance

Tags: python, function, class

I have a class lets call it EmployeeProfile.
That collects a bunch of data about a person.

I would like to be able to update specific data within the class using a function.

```
class EmployeeProfile:
def __init__(self, profile):
    self.displayname = profile.get('displayName')
    self.email = profile.get('email')
    self.firstname = profile.get('firstName')
    self.surname = profile.get('surname')
    self.fullname = profile.get('fullName')
    self.costcode = profile.get('work').get('custom')

def update(self, operation, value):

    def manageremail(value):
        self.manageremail = value

    def costline(value):
        self.costline = value
```

Is there a way to use one update function to specify what attribute to update, and run the relevant nested function?

```
class Ted()
Ted.update('manageremail', 'noreply@me.com)
```

I would like to be able to expand on the update function so I can update any of the attributes of the class.

Comment: There's `setattr`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr

Comment: You can just use `__dict__` attribute to modify the values directly. It's just like a dictionary, and if you update it, the object's attributes will be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have plenty of options. Some of them include using `setattr()`, updating the `__dict__` or using a custom dictionary:

```
class EmployeeProfile:
  ATTRIBUTES = {"email", "displayname"}
  def __init__(self, profile):
    self.displayname = profile.get('displayName')
    self.email = profile.get('email')
    ...
  def update(self, attribute, value):
      if attribute not in self.ATTRIBUTES:
          raise ValueError(f"Invalid attribute {attribute!r}")
      setattr(self, attribute, value)

employee = EmployeeProfile({})

# All of these are practically equivalent
employee.update("email", "stuff@stuff")
employee.__dict__["email"] = "stuff@stuff2"
setattr(employee, "email", "stuff@stuff3")  # <--- Personally I'd choose this.
employee.email = "stuff@stuff4"  # <---- Or this.
```

Some random points:

- A custom `update()` function allows you to set specific attributes
  that are updatable and the rest aren't, or do more complex logic
  without using `@property`.
- `setattr` is very simple and plays well with `@property` later on should you need.
- Using `__dict__.update()` allows you to update multiple values at once, i.e `employee.update({"email": "rawr@rawr", "displayname": "John"})`, but doesn't allow property decorators.
- `.email` is best but the attribute name is static.

Comment: Perfect explanation thank you so much.....